# Generate overlay on user submitted photos in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, overlay

Does anyone know of a wordpress plugin that would allow for users to submit photos that we would then automatically add a custom overlay to? Similar to: https://yearoftheelephant.org/ or the way facebook generates overlays like the rainbow overlay. We would create the overlay and apply the same one to every image. I've searched for an appropriate plugin with no success. This might be too advanced for wordpress? I work for a nonprofit dedicated to saving orangutans, so any leads are greatly appreciated and beneficial to the planet!! (:

Comment: Is there only going to be one overlay for all uploaded photos? Or should the user be capable of selecting one of the overlays?

Comment: Only 1 overlay would be necessary.

Comment: Can you send me the url of your site?

Comment: www.orangutan.org

Comment: sorry Emily, I meant a url to the page where you want to place the overlays

Comment: I could quickly help / or set up the proper structure to match your needs when I see where you want to place the overlay.